# Standard output in Hadoop on Google Compute Engine

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop, logging, google-compute-engine

I am trying to debug a program running on Hadoop on Google Compute Engine as a .jar file. I tried using both `System.out.println()` and `context.write()` inside the reducer code for debug output but can't find their output anywhere. The only logs I could find were the ones in my Google bucket `gs:/my_bucket/yarn-logs/my_name/logs/application_#####` and local logs stored in `$hadoop_install_dir$/logs/` but none of them has the output I am looking for. In the former logs I can see that my log4j wasn't initialized properly but I am not sure if this is the problem and/or how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the stdout from your Map and Reduce tasks on the actual worker nodes, under `${HADOOP_INSTALL_DIR}/logs/userlogs/application_*/container*/stdout` if you used "Click-to-Deploy", or under `/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_*/container*/stdout` if you used `bdutil` to deploy.

Comment: The userlogs folder is empty. Can this be a problem with the log4j setup?

Comment: Hmm, log4j setup shouldn't affect the System.out.println at least. If it was an old job, then the userlogs may have been getting clobbered due to `mapreduce.job.userlog.retain.hours` defaulting to 24 hours if not specified in `.mapred-site.xml`. Have you tried testing with a quick sample mapreduce where you System.out.println() a bunch in your map and reduce tasks and then trying to "grep -R <your message> /hadoop/logs/userlogs /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/logs/userlogs"?

Comment: Thanks, I actually finally found the desired output in the gs://my_bucket/yarn-logs directory